# Camel: Content based routing, from different froms

Tags: java, apache-camel, apache-karaf, fuseesb

I have two programs, made up of three routes.

```
[  
one is a route, from JPA database to bean.  
one is a copier, from file system endpoint to file system endpoint  
]

[  
one is a uploader, from file system endpoint to bean.  
]
```

I want to run the one program based on input from my property file

```
<context:property-placeholder location="./run.properties"
    ignore-resource-not-found="false" />
```

But all I can find for content-based-routing, is examples where the choose is below the from.  eg.

```
from("direct:start")
    .choice()
        .when(body().contains("Camel"))
            .loadBalance().roundRobin().to("mock:foo").to("mock:bar")
        .otherwise()
            .to("mock:result");
```

I want a way to rearrange to something like this:

```
choice()
   .when(body().contains("Camel"))
      from("direct:start1").loadBalance().roundRobin().to("mock:foo").to("mock:bar")
   .otherwise()
      from("direct:start2").to("mock:result");
```

Comment: What you want? Are you want to start different route based on the properties?

Comment: Exactly.  I figure there is some sort of Spring EL to handle this, but I can't find it.

Comment: If you are using Java DSL (http://camel.apache.org/java-dsl.html), you can programmatically to start route. Simple way is read properties and write if else statement in the route.

Comment: If it is working, please post your own answer to question.

Answer (score 2):

you don't need content based routing to control whether routes are started...

just use the `autoStartup(boolean)` API to control this...

for example...

```
from("activemq:queue:special").autoStartup("{{startupRouteProperty}}").to("file://backup");
```

see http://camel.apache.org/configuring-route-startup-ordering-and-autostartup.html

Comment: i don't see how this helps me choose between two different routes, or from's, based on a config file.

Comment: your question seemed to be about calling sub routes from a CBR, which the enrich patterns allows...anyways, I updated my answer accordingly

Comment: thanks, that looks like a viable solution.  I ended up converting to Java, as hutingung suggested.  It ain't broken, so I won't fix it, but next time will try this.

Answer (score 0):

The way I ended up doing it:

```
static ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context;
static CamelContext camel;
```

...

```
        context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml");
        camel = new SpringCamelContext(context);
```

...

```
    if (property) {
        camel.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from(..).to(..)
            }
        });
    } else {
        camel.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from(..).to(..)
            }
        });
    }

    camel.start();
```